# Folders and files lost from Desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files

All my folders and files were lost from my Desktop yesterday. I can not find them.

I wanted to have two Firefox profiles on Ubuntu 14.04 so [I followed this tutorial](https://chrisjean.com/multiple-firefox-profiles-in-ubuntu/).

After I run Firefox profile manager and  clicked **Create profile** then **Next** this window showed

[image: Create new profile]

Here I clicked **Choose Folder** and I choose Desktop. I think that was the problem.

I can not find any file or folder.
I tried:

```
~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

and

```
killall nautilus
```

Didn't  help.

Also :

```
find . -name filename
```

Didn't  help

```
ls -l ~/Desktop
```

Didn't  help too

In GIMP I tried to open the last file (that was saved on Desktop)  but no success

I tried to login using the Ubuntu 2D but no success.

I don't know what can I do next. Any help ?